# Secure credentials for spring integration mail idle imap channel adapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration Mail to pull emails from Exchange Server and then process them. It seems all work fine so far. Now, I need to **not expose credentials** in configuration. Any ideas on how to pass these credentials to the idle-channel-adapter in a secured way?

I am planning to deploy this in Weblogic Server. Below is an example of the inbound adapter.

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
  store-uri="imaps://[username]:[password]@[exchange-imap-server]:993/INBOX"
  channel="receiveChannel"
  auto-startup="true"
  should-delete-messages="false"
  should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
  auto-close-folder="false"
  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for this purpose there is a *properties placeholder* abstraction and functionality in Spring Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-extension.

So, your config would look like this:

```
store-uri="imaps://${username}:${password}@${exchange-imap-server}:993/INBOX"
```

And then you can have a `.properties` file, or you can store those variables into Weblogic system properties or environment variables with actual secret values. Something like this:

```
username=my_login
password=my_password
exchange-imap-server=IMAP_SERVER_URL
```

Since you have Spring Boot, you don't need to configure that `<context:property-placeholder>` in your application context.